# Why did I not get notified that my question was closed?

Tags: discussion, feature-request, status-completed

I posed a [question](https://money.meta.stackexchange.com/posts/10/revisions) on **meta.money.stackexchange.com** and ticked the "*Notify (email address) daily of any new answers*" option.

The question was closed by an attentive moderator less than 20 minutes later, however I was not notified of this.

Now, I know it says "*Notify [...] **of any new answers***" but I would argue that closing a question, specifically when closed **as duplicate**, is actually providing new answers, by transitivity. (If I'm interested in the answer to a question, then the fact that there is an exact duplicate question, probably with answers of its own, would be of interest too!)

Separately to this, the closure of the question didn't show up in my 'Recent Activity' listing either. I'd argue that question closure, of any type, would be of interest and should be shown here.

Should question closures be notified by email and/or appear in 'Recent Activity'?

Comment: Post authors and followers now receive inbox notificaitons on [close](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/356742/question-closed-notifications-experiment-results-and-graduation) events.